# How to display the label as two lines for DateTime on XtraChart?

Tags: datetime, devexpress, customization, axis-labels, xtrachart

I have a DevExpress XtraChart LineChart control, and its argument is DateTime. I use the AxisX.DateTimeOptions.Format = DateTimeFormat.General, it will display year, month, day, hour, minute, but the labels will overlap each other. I know in DevExpress 15.1 version, we have new property to resolve this. But unfortunately I am on version 10.1 and I cannot upgrade for now.

I want to display the label as two lines: the first line just displays yyyy-MM-dd, and the second line just displays h:mm tt, how could I achieve this? How should I set the FormatString? Or shall I use the AxisX.DateTimeOptions.Format = DateTimeFormat.Custom or something else?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure this out:
We can use

LineChart_CustomDrawAxisLabel

```
    private void LineChart_CustomDrawAxisLabel(object sender, CustomDrawAxisLabelEventArgs e)
    {
        AxisBase axis = e.Item.Axis;
        if (axis is AxisX)
        {
            string dateTimeString = e.Item.Text;
            var result = dateTimeString.Split(' ');

            e.Item.Text = result[0] + System.Environment.NewLine + result[1] + result[2];
        }
    }
```